# How to bring iTerm to front of screen or back shortcut

Tags: macos, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I was wondering if there was a way to set a keyboard shortcut to send terminal to the back, behind other windows and then back to the front. Cmd-tab is the only way I can think of, but not a good option as I often have many windows of the same application.

Comment: You may have more luck getting an answer, if you ask on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) (the StackExchange site dedicated to all things Apple).

Answer (score 10):

You can do it via Hotkey option.

Goto **Preferences** -> **Keys** tab -> **Hotkey** section -> Set a shortcut key combination.

By this, when you are in the other application, the same shortcut in application level will not work.
For instance, if you set **CMD+SHIFT+J** as the hotkey, now if you switch to chrome, then **CMD+SHIFT+J** will not open downloads page in Chrome. It switches back to the iTerm window.